# Popover wrong position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have made a popover. And it is made from the storyboard so not programmatically or anything. 
But the problem is that the position of it is a bit off.

[image: Picture of wrong position]

I want the position of that arrow and that to be just under my button

Like this

[image]

My storyboard where is look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS9 glitch, works as expected under iOS8. Apple is probably going to fix this with an upcoming update.